# Reversing a specific Rails Migration, can't remove

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, migration

```
class UpdateIndexOnUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    sql = 'DROP INDEX index_users_on_email'
  sql << ' ON users' if Rails.env == 'production' # Heroku pg
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
  end
end
```

I have to undo this migration. When I revert it using `rake db:migrate VERSION=20150611173430`,I get this error.

```
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at end of input
LINE 1: CREATE INDEX index_users_on_email
                                         ^
    : CREATE INDEX index_users_on_email/Users/goda/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `async_exec'
```

Then I add a NEW migration file to try and reverse that.

```
class FixUpdateIndexOnUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    sql = 'CREATE INDEX index_users_on_email'
    sql << ' ON users' if Rails.env == 'production' # Heroku pg
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
  end
end
```

BUT on heroku, `heroku run rake db:migrate` fails. Because it runs into that syntax error on the first migration that I cannot remove. What should be done?

EDIT: Fixed syntax, still throwing an error.

```
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ON"
LINE 1: DROP INDEX index_users_on_email ON users;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a change method rather than an up, which you should only do for the subset of migrations that rails can reverse automatically.

You should change the change method to up, and add a down method that can reverse the effects of the up method.

Comment: Can i simply modify the migration file I have already db:migrated?

Comment: Yes, sure. That would be the best way -- delete the second migration and correct the methods on the first.

Comment: Thanks, I thought migrations had to be dealt with properly in one of the rails generators. I just deleted the def change and it worked during db:rollback and db:migration.